# Dragging properties into a Quiver dashboard

Tags: palantir-foundry

In Quiver, while building a dashboard to display a limited set of properties for a monthly reporting overview, I would like to know if it's possible to have a list of additional properties on the left side that can be easily dragged and dropped into the dashboard. This functionality is common in reporting systems like SAP BW, where you can effortlessly add columns that are not initially visible in the report.

I can not find anything in the documentation or in the examples

Answer (score 1):

Which widget are you referring to, the table widget? I don't think this is possible in the manner you describe.

A work-around might be creating a second tab with the same table widget configured to show more columns so it's just a click away for your end users.

[image: Clicking between two tabs to display different properties in a table]

Comment: He thanks for the info and I guess you are right. The employees can choose out of too many fields to add and says something about the organization. A quick other question. In Quiver I need to add a column from an other (linked) object set into an existing object set or table. Checked all docu but no solution. Can you help?

Comment: Post that as another question so future users can find it :)